# Change parameter inside dispatch_async from main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, dispatch-async

I have an IOS application written in Swift. I want to change a variable from main thread when a button is pressed and want to use the same variable inside the function to skip NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval() call.

Original function in main class:

```
func setTextWithAnimation(myLabel: UILabel, typedText: String, characterInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0.05){
    myLabel.text = ""
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
        for character in Array(typedText) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                myLabel.text = myLabel.text! + String(character)
            }
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(characterInterval)
        }
    }
}
```

I changed this to:

```
var skipThisText = false

func setTextWithAnimation(myLabel: UILabel, typedText: String, characterInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0.05){
    myLabel.text = ""
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
        for character in Array(typedText) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                myLabel.text = myLabel.text! + String(character)
            }
            if !skipThisText {
                NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(characterInterval)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func skipTextAnimationButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    skipThisText = true
}
```

But it does not work because the main thread does not communicate with the block in the dispatch_async(..). And I have to use dispatch_async() block to have the text animation

Is there a simple workaround? What should I change to skip NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval() when the button is pressed?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but the code you're executing in the block doesn't look too hard. I think you can directly call it in the main thread, it will not slow the UI at all.

Comment: I have tried it. But, It takes about a 3-4 seconds to fill up the UILabel. and there is at least 3 of them. They are simultaneously working now. But, If I call it in the main thread, It waits about 3 seconds to open the first segue window. But I did not try to load other components first, then load UILabel in main thread. (Thought of this now, will try in a minute)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. I don't see any animation. Your loop looks like a simple "label.text = typedText".

Comment: it's a simplified version of the function.